# get byte array from datatable to list c#

Tags: c#, arrays, list, datatable

I gave a `byte[]` stored in database,

I get the byte array in my `DataTable` from sql

[image]

this is my `DataTable`, System.byte[] is my image in bytes which is stored in my datatbase

now I want to convert this `DataTable` into list

this is my current Code

```
var answerList = (from rw in dt.AsEnumerable()
                    select new RegistrationAnswers()
                    {
                        responseID = rw["responseID"].ToString() == string.Empty ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(rw["responseID"].ToString()),
                        responseRegID = rw["responseRegID"].ToString() == string.Empty ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(rw["responseRegID"].ToString()), 
                        responseAnswer = rw["responseAnswer"].ToString(),
                        _ResponseDocument =  rw["responseDocument"], //here i want to validate if rw["responseDocument"] is null or not and if this is not null then assign the byte[] data to _ResponseDocument 
                        formID=Convert.ToInt32(rw["formID"])
                    }).ToList();
```

when I updated my code to

```
//At top
byte[] tempByteArray = new byte[0];

_responseDocument = Convert.IsDBNull((byte[])rw["responseDocument"]) == false ? tempByteArray : (byte[])rw["responseDocument"],
```

I am getting following error

'Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.Byte[]'.'

> i want to validate if rw["responseDocument"] is null or not and if
>   this is not null then assign the byte[] data to _ResponseDocument

Comment: What should _ResponseDocument be if the byte data is null ?

Comment: _ResponseDocument = (rw["responseDocument"]==null)?null:LoadBytesSomeHowFor(rw)

Comment: You seem to be checking whether IsDBNull is false and assigning a tempByte array if it is false i.e. if it's not null, you're assigning the tempByteArray. This seems to be the wrong way round

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the same problem while getting the data from `DataTable` into `list`

what I did is created a byte array in the method

```
byte[] tempByteArray = new byte[0];
```

and in my loop did something like this

```
_responseDocument = rw["responseDocument"].ToString() == "" ? tempByteArray : (byte[])rw["responseDocument"],
```

Answer (score 2):

Try casting

```
rw["responseDocument"] == System.DBNull.Value ? new byte[0] : (byte[])rw["responseDocument"];
```

or

```
Convert.IsDBNull(rw["responseDocument"]) ? new byte[0] : (byte[])rw["responseDocument"];
```

Comment: @stuartd check the question - the answer is apt, and almost certainly correct

Comment: for the OP's benefit: the problem here is that in the code in the question, you are casting to `byte[]` *before* checking for `DBNull` - the code shown here casts only *after* the `DBNull` check

Comment: If `rw` is a `DataRow` (which from surrounding code I suspect it is), it has an `IsNull` method that can be called rather than retrieving and comparing the `DBNull` value.